# Javascript rotation animation from a rotated position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-animations

I want to create a hand hour. The start position is `0 deg`. If i click a button, the hand hour rotate to `X deg` with animation, and stay here, in `X deg`.
Next time, I click the button, start a new rotation animation, and the hand hour rotate to `X + Y deg` from `X deg`, not the start `0 deg`. How this operation is possible?

Comment: You need to store the state of the hand.

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=hand+hour

Comment: Can you include in your question what you have tried so far? Please understand, we aren't here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the computed angle, increment it, and then update the CSS using JS.

```js
const hand = document.querySelector('.hand'),
      loop = document.querySelector('.loop'),
      refreshRate = 60, tickAngle = 3;

let loopId = null;

const startStop = (e) => {
  if (loopId) {
    clearInterval(loopId); loopId = null;
  } else {
    loopId = setInterval(tick, 1000 / refreshRate);
  }
  loop.textContent = loopId ? 'Stop' : 'Start';
};

const tick = () => {
  const degrees = (getCurrentAngle(hand) + tickAngle) % 360;
  hand.style.transform = `rotate(${degrees}deg)`;
};

// Adapted from:
// https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/
const getCurrentAngle = (el) => {
  const st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null),
        tr = st.getPropertyValue('-webkit-transform') ||
             st.getPropertyValue('-moz-transform') ||
             st.getPropertyValue('-ms-transform') ||
             st.getPropertyValue('-o-transform') ||
             st.getPropertyValue('transform'),
       [a, b] = tr.match(/^matrix\((.+)\)$/)[1].split(/,\s*/g).map(Number);
  return Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180 / Math.PI));
};

loop.addEventListener('click', startStop);
```

```css
.face {
  position: relative;
  border: 0.25em solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
}

.hand {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.25em;
  height: 3.5em;
  background: red;
  left: 4em;
  top: 4em;
  transform-origin: 0.125em 0; /* x = width / 2 */
  transform: rotate(180deg);   /* Start at 0th hour */
}
```

```html
<div class="face">
  <div class="hand">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="loop">Start</button>
</div>
```